# I have this error: No routes matched location "/edit?..." in React.js of API Meme Generator

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm building one API of Meme Generator in React and I have this issue.
The error occurs when I press the button Edit in the Homepage and I'm in the Edit route, the title render but don't the image to edit.

The codes are these:

The App.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import Homepage from "./pages/Home";
import EditPage from "./pages/Edit";

import './App.css';

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>App Meme Generator</h1>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
          <Route path="/edit/:url" element={<EditPage/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default App;
```

The Home.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CardMeme from "../components/Card";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllMemes } from "../api/memes";

const Homepage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllMemes().then((meme) => setData(meme.data.memes));
  }, []);

  const handleEditClick = (url) => {
    navigate(`/edit/${url}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {data.map((el) => (
        <CardMeme
          key={el.id}
          img={el.url}
          title={el.name}
          onEditClick={() => handleEditClick(el.url)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

The Card.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const CardMeme = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '25px' }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.img} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
            <Button onClick={e => navigate(`/edit?url=${props.img}`)} variant="primary">Edit</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default CardMeme;
```

The Edit.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import Text from "../components/Text";
import { Button } from "bootstrap";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { exportComponentAsJPEG } from "react-component-export-image";

const EditPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log(params.get("url"));

  const memeRef = createRef();

  const addText = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "700px" }} ref={memeRef} className="meme mt-5 mb-5">
        <img src={params.get("url")} width="250px" />
        {Array(count)
          .fill(0)
          .map((_, index) => (
            <Text key={index} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <Button onClick={addText}>Añadir Texto</Button>
      <Button variant="success" onClick={(e) => exportComponentAsJPEG(memeRef)}>
        Save
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditPage;
```

I tried to correct how I passed the Edit path, but I couldn't get anything.

I tried to correct the problem modifying the Edit path but I can't solve it.
I would like to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What url are you trying to serve?  I see the error about ```edit?``` but you have ```edit/```.  Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: Are you wanting to use the path parameter `:url` or the query parameter `?url`?

Comment: I want to use the query parameter ?url and one url for example is this: https://i.imgflip.com/1g8my4.jpg Thanks for the welcome!